# JQuery Filer post files on submit

Tags: asp.net, jquery-filer

Trying to use jquery.filer to upload images to my controller in asp.net mvc. Everything works as expected if I simply use the HTML file input type but once I enable the plugin it stops populating HttpPostedFileBase property.

After reading the documentation I couldn't find anyway of simply attaching the files to the input and uploading them on submit.

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, ListingModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

**JS**

```
    $("#filer_input").filer({
    limit: 6,
    maxSize: 5,
    extensions: null,
    changeInput: '<div class="jFiler-input-dragDrop"><div class="jFiler-input-inner"><div class="jFiler-input-icon"><i class="icon-jfi-cloud-up-o"></i></div><div class="jFiler-input-text"><h3>Drag&Drop files here</h3> <span style="display:inline-block; margin: 15px 0">or</span></div><a class="jFiler-input-choose-btn blue">Browse Files</a></div></div>',
    showThumbs: true,
    theme: "dragdropbox",
    templates: {
        box: '<ul class="jFiler-items-list jFiler-items-grid"></ul>',
        item: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                    <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                    <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                    <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                </div>\
                                {{fi-image}}\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                    <li>{{fi-progressBar}}</li>\
                                </ul>\
                                <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                    <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                </ul>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </li>',
        itemAppend: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                    </div>\
                                    {{fi-image}}\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                        <li><span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-icon}}</span></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                        <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </li>',
        progressBar: '<div class="bar"></div>',
        itemAppendToEnd: true,
        removeConfirmation: true,
        _selectors: {
            list: '.jFiler-items-list',
            item: '.jFiler-item',
            progressBar: '.bar',
            remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action'
        }
    },
    dragDrop: {
        dragEnter: null,
        dragLeave: null,
        drop: null
    },
    //uploadFile: {
    //    url: "./php/upload.php",
    //    data: null,
    //    type: 'POST',
    //    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    //    beforeSend: function(){},
    //    success: function(data, el){
    //        var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
    //        el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    //            $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");    
    //        });
    //    },
    //    error: function(el){
    //        var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
    //        el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    //            $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-error\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-minus-circle\"></i> Error</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");    
    //        });
    //    },
    //    statusCode: null,
    //    onProgress: null,
    //    onComplete: null
    //},
    addMore: false,
    clipBoardPaste: true,
    excludeName: null,
    beforeRender: null,
    afterRender: null,
    beforeShow: null,
    beforeSelect: null,
    onSelect: null,
    afterShow: null,
    //onRemove: function(itemEl, file, id, listEl, boxEl, newInputEl, inputEl){
    //    var file = file.name;
    //    $.post('./php/remove_file.php', {file: file});
    //},
    onEmpty: null,
    options: null,
    captions: {
        button: "Choose Files",
        feedback: "Choose files To Upload",
        feedback2: "files were chosen",
        drop: "Drop file here to Upload",
        removeConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to remove this file?",
        errors: {
            filesLimit: "Only {{fi-limit}} files are allowed to be uploaded.",
            filesType: "Only Images are allowed to be uploaded.",
            filesSize: "{{fi-name}} is too large! Please upload file up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB.",
            filesSizeAll: "Files you've choosed are too large! Please upload files up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB."
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
                        <div class="form-group clearfix">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 padding-left-0 padding-right-0">
                            <input type="file" name="files" id="filer_input2" multiple="multiple">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work if you are using `drag&drop` and `uploadFile` feature. If you want to get the files from `<input type="file">` you will need to disable this 2 options in your jQuery.filer